# Can we use "AとBとはC" and "AとBとではC" interchangeably?

Tags: grammar

> 知識としては比較的早い段階で保有していた情報。きっと『海』というものについて質問をされたなら、普通の人よりも詳細に説明をすることが可能だったろう。
>
> けれど、頭の中になったそれと、今五感を以て感じているもの**とは**、存在感が、ディティールが、まるで異なっていた。

Can we say "...今五感を以て感じているもの**とでは**" in that sentence? What would be the difference between "AとBとはC" and "AとBとではC"? Or are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sentence sounds a bit unnatural to me. Replacing とは with either では or とでは would make it sound more natural.

> Aと、Bとは、存在感が異なっていた。(a bit unnatural)

> Aと、Bでは、存在感が異なっていた。(natural)

> Aと、Bとでは、存在感が異なっていた。(natural)

The scope of comparison or contrast becomes much clearer with で.

とは may be used alone to indicate contrast but that’s due to the collocation of 〜と（は）異なる.

> Aは、Bとは、存在感がまるで異なっていた。(natural)

Having said that, though, それとこれとは話が違う seems more commonly used than それとこれでは話が違う or それとこれとでは話が違う. It’s almost like an idiom as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

> "AとBとはC" and "AとBとではC"

they have the same use in this case.
Precisely speaking, `"異なる"` means `"is different"`, so `"AとBとは異なる"` means `"A and B is different"`,

and when someone says `"AとBとでは異なる"`, we Japanse get the feeling that `"A is different from B. But there's an existence of another element that resembles A"`.

To add some information, "それ" means"海"